# Show another window wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been looking around the Internet but I am not sure if there is a way to show 2 classes in wxPython in 2 separate windows. And could we communicate between them (like one class being the dialog and the other the main class)?

I think I did this before using `Show()` but I am not sure how to repeat this.

So basically I would like to be able to have a dialog but by using a class instead. This would be more powerful than using Modal dialogs.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have a simple example of two frames communicating:

[image]

The trick is in sending an object reference to share between frames, either creating one inside the other (as in this case) or through a common parent.
The code is:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(150,100), title='MainFrame')
        pan =wx.Panel(self)
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(pan, -1, pos=(0,0), size=(100,20), style=wx.DEFAULT)
        self.but = wx.Button(pan,-1, pos=(10,30), label='Tell child')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onbutton, self.but)
        self.child = ChildFrame(self)
        self.child.Show()

    def onbutton(self, evt):
        text = self.txt.GetValue()
        self.child.txt.write('Parent says: %s' %text)


class ChildFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(150,100), title='ChildFrame')
        self.parent = parent
        pan = wx.Panel(self)
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(pan, -1, pos=(0,0), size=(100,20), style=wx.DEFAULT)
        self.but = wx.Button(pan,-1, pos=(10,30), label='Tell parent')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onbutton, self.but)

    def onbutton(self, evt):
        text = self.txt.GetValue()
        self.parent.txt.write('Child says: %s' %text)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    App=wx.PySimpleApp()
    MainFrame().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pubsub to communicate between two frames. I show one way of doing just that in this article: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

If you don't want the first frame to hide itself, just remove the line with the Hide() in it.