# 2 "parallel" wxpython GUIs possible?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, parallel-processing, wxpython

I just started a new job.  Existing code is wxpython GUI that is partially implemented.  The jist is that there are 2 independent GUIs: one is a "status monitor with test abort button" and the other is a test executive, running tests that might take a few minutes.

At any time, the status monitor GUI abort button should be able to be pressed to stop the long running test script process running in the executive GUI.

The long script process is started in a new thread and is working from the test executive GUI, but no matter what I do, the status monitor GUI is frozen.

Ive done similar things in pyside and it didnt seem to be as much of a bear as with wxpython.

I don think this is a thread problem.  seems like its a wxpython problem.

Is it possible to have 2 independent wxpython GUIs started from the same script? I seem to have read somewhere that im required to have only one main loop.

Any hints/examples of 2 parallel independent GUIs would be great!

Comment: Nothing prevents you from launching multiple independent windows from the same wxpython application. They will all share the same event loop, however. You should not keep the main thread (the event loop) busy anyway (that is not a shortcoming). Otherwise the gui will hang. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263513/show-another-window-wxpython) for a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

As far as I know, it is not possible to run 2 GUIs just seperated by threads.

We had a quite similar problem. And as we are using Windows mainly, we needed to work around the Python GIL, to enable the GUI to stop the subprocess which executes the tests.

In order to do so, we moved to multiprocessing library and we are using a Processpool which executes the tests (we are running multiple items at the same time - you can use just a process for your purpose). In a new process you will also be able to execute a second GUI, which is completely independent (We are doing this as well). When using another process, it gets a PID, which can be used with os.kill. The main GUI will stay stable throughout this.

To communicate with the new process we use Pyro4, but you could also use a approach with Queues to get the communication done. You cannot directly access data from another process if you are using Windows like with the threading approach.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Michael